# Did Hillary Clinton pay Russian officials 30 million dollars, through her campaign to get dirt on Trump?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump, russia, hillary-clinton

In tonight's episode of Real Time with Bill Maher, [Ann Coulter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ann_Coulter) said:

> I mean, Hillary Clinton paid, through her campaign, 30 million dollars to Russian officials to get dirt on Trump

The full interview including the quote above can be seen on [Youtube (starting at 8:32)](https://youtu.be/EzBYxqtJSqc?t=508).

Is the statement accurate? Is there evidence that Hillary Clinton paid Russian officials 30 million dollars, through her campaign to get dirt on Trump?

Comment: "Did Hillary Clinton's *campaign* pay..." - She was only worth $45M in 2017. Her *personally* paying $30M through her campaign would be the silliest thing I've ever heard.

Comment: Your title places an interjection in the original context making it an even more ambiguous statement, unless read carefully. *Did "Hillary Clinton [pay], through her campaign" 30 million dollars to get dirt on Trump?*

Comment: @Mazura better like this? If not, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If we listen a couple of seconds longer, Coulter specifies that it's about the "fusion GPS story", so it's about the [Trump-Russia dossier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump%E2%80%93Russia_dossier).

## Cost of the dossier

There are a number of claims out there:

- [$168k](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-russia-dossier/ex-british-spy-paid-168000-for-trump-dossier-u-s-firm-discloses-idUSKBN1D15XH) paid by Fusion GPS to Orbis/Steel, according to Fusion GPS. This is the money - minus Steels salary and operational costs - that theoretically could have gone to Russian officials
- [$1.02M](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-russia/trump-ally-roger-stone-arrested-for-lying-to-u-s-congress-idUSKCN1PJ16M) paid by the law firm of the DNC and the Clinton campaign to Fusion GPS, according to Fusion GPS. This is the total cost of the dossier.
- [$5.6 million](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/357185-trump-claims-clinton-6m-for-dossier-research) / [$12.4M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump%E2%80%93Russia_dossier#Reactions) paid by the Clinton campaign to Clintons law firm - this is likely where the following $6M/$12M claims originate. Clintons law firm likely performed other actions than only paying Fusion GPS.
- [$6M](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/357185-trump-claims-clinton-6m-for-dossier-research)/[$12M](https://www.newsweek.com/trump-dossier-cost-millions-699816) paid by Clinton, according to Trump (who didn't give sources for the claim).

I was unable to find any source putting the number at 30 million, even unsourced claims by Trump seem to be $12 million at most. The only sourced claim I could find is $1 million.

## Who paid for the dossier

The money paid to Fusion GPS did not come from the Clinton campaign alone, but also from the [DNC](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/clinton-campaign-dnc-paid-for-research-that-led-to-russia-dossier/2017/10/24/226fabf0-b8e4-11e7-a908-a3470754bbb9_story.html):

> People involved in the matter said that they would not disclose the dollar amounts paid to Fusion GPS but that the [Hillary Clinton] campaign and the DNC shared the cost.

## How was the money used

According to the [Fusion GPS co-founder](https://edition.cnn.com/2017/11/15/politics/russia-investigation-fusion-gps-glenn-simpson-dossier/index.html), Steel didn't pay his sources.

## Conclusion

The cost of the dossier was $1 million paid by the DNC and the Clinton campaign to Fusion GPS, of which $168K were given to Steel.

Even the unsourced high end guesses of the costs of the dossier are well below $30 million, and only a tiny fraction of that could have gone to Russian officials.

Comment: Don't forget that the work by Fusion GPS was *started and initially funded by Republican primary opponents of Trump*. I don't know if there are any estimates of that portion of the work, and how they compare to the figures you include.